# pythonic way to simplify if clause with multiple values

Tags: python, if-statement

```
import os
for file in ['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt']:
    if not os.path.exists(os.getcwd() + '\\' + file):
        print(fr'{file} is missing')
```

Basically, I would like to place a.txt, b.txt, c.txt into the os.path.exists function one by one, and then, inside the if clause, I would like to print the message with the file name included. I have no idea how to make it pythonic. I see people write "in" with "if" in one line, but I have no idea how to do that in my case, as I have a print function that uses the value "file" too.

Again, I want to make it efficient, pythonic.

Comment: You will need a `for` loop as you are trying to check if each file exists or not.

Comment: It's pretty Pythonic to me. It's easy to read and understand and I'm not sure what you seek to achieve with changing it.

Comment: It seems like you're thinking of `if file in ('a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt'):` but that's testing something completely different.

Comment: Your code is about as good as it can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by "pythonic". One thing which would be that is to use modern stdlib modules e.g. `pathlib`:

```py
from pathlib import Path
for file in ['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt']:
    if not (path.cwd() / file).exists():
        print(fr'{file} is missing')
```

Not using unnecessary bits is probably pythonic as well: the `r` string prefix is completely unnecessary.

You could also go the functional route, but AFAIK it's not really favored. It could be used to "merge" some of the complicated bits together, as well as avoid repeated calls to `cwd`, though:

```py
from pathlib import Path
for file in map(path.cwd().joinpath, ['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt']):
    if not file.exists():
        print(f'{file.name} is missing')
```

I would also avoid the name `file`: I'd assume it to be an actual file object (aka the output of `open`), but that's more of a personal thing.

Comment: Best comment ever seen, really want to double tick your answer, though stackoverflow does not have that function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `os.path.join` function instead of concatenation:

```
import os
for file in ['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt']:
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file)):
        print(fr'{file} is missing')
```